# Express request reissued on timeout

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

For some reason if app is not process request in time its 'get' callback is called again. In my opinion this is horribly wrong. Client sent only one request and the server should process it once. Now with client retry logic we're having spawn of ghost requests in a large amount.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var counter = 0;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('->\tget', ++counter);
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.send('ok');
  }, 5000);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.info('Server port:', server.address().port);
});
server.timeout = 1000;
```

Output:

```
Server port: 3000
->      get 1
->      get 2               <----- Here is ghost request i didn't made!!!
```

Is it bug in the express or some feature?

Comment: "*Now with client retry logic ...*" A "retry" in HTTP client is only possible as a new request to the same resource after abandoning the previous. To the server, these requests will appear to be separate and unrelated.

Comment: Looks like you're right it is not related to express. It is reproducing on pure nodejs using Firefox or Chrome or .Net HttpWebRequest. And it is not reproducing on IE or Edge.